# using javascript/jQuery to show certain elements on certain dates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty much as the title. I have been asked if it is possible to have a specific banner shown in a section on a website on different days without any external user input.

My first thoughts are the use of javascript/jquery. We are limited with the functionality however as the site is controlled by the horror that is Netsuite.

Any help/ideas are appreciated :)

-Wayne

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** With regard to your comment, it sounds like you want to load a different slideshow depending on the day of the week.

Here's a simple generic example of how it could be done.

```
  // Insert the code that loads the individual slideshows in the functions below
var slideshows = [
    function() { /* insert code to load some slideshow */ },
    function() { /* insert code to load some other slideshow */ },
    function() { /* insert code to load a different slideshow */ },
    function() { /* insert code to load yet another slideshow */ }
];
  // call a slideshow function depending on the day of week
slideshows[ new Date().getDate() % slideshows.length ]();
```

This will call a different function from the Array depending on the day of week. You don't need seven of them. It will automatically rotate.

There are other ways to approach this, but I'd need to see how the slideshows are set up. This is a simple approach.

If you have more than 7 different slideshows, it will need to be changed a bit.

---

**EDIT:** *This answer assumes you meant different per day of week. Not sure if that was your intention.*

---

This is probably better than my original answer since it doesn't require loading all the banners.

*javascript only version*

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/5drgu/4/

```
var banners = [
    "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/f00/fff.png&text=my+image",
    "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/0f0/fff.png&text=my+image",
    "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/00f/fff.png&text=my+image",
    "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/ff0/fff.png&text=my+image"
    ];
var banner = new Image();
banner.src = banners[ new Date().getDate() % banners.length ];
document.getElementById('container').appendChild( banner );
```

---

*jQuery version*

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/5drgu/7/

*(changed it a bit so it doesn't start with an empty `<img>`)*

```
var banners = [
    "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/f00/fff.png&text=my+image",
    "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/0f0/fff.png&text=my+image",
    "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/00f/fff.png&text=my+image",
    "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/ff0/fff.png&text=my+image"
    ];
var banner =  $('<img>', { src:banners[ new Date().getDate() % banners.length ]})
                          .appendTo('#container');
```

*html*

```
<div id='container'></div>
```

---

**Original answer:**

<s>Here's one way:</s>

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/5drgu/

```
var banners = $('#container img').hide();
banners.eq( new Date().getDate() % banners.length ).show();
```

*html*

```
<div id='container'>
   <img src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/f00/fff.png&text=my+image" />
   <img src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/0f0/fff.png&text=my+image" />
   <img src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/00f/fff.png&text=my+image" />
   <img src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/ff0/fff.png&text=my+image" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the indepth reply. Ill admit im not familiar with javascript/jquery at all other than implementing pretty much ready made scripts into existing websites.

You are right in thinking that I want it to be a different banner per day over a number of days.

As far as implementation is concerned, would it be possible to add this into an already established jquery rotating banner script? you can see the one in use here : http://www.gardensandhomesdirect.co.uk

Comment: @Wayners247: Yes, if you wanted a different slide show per day of week, you could do something similar. Not sure how your slideshow gets set up, but one simple approach would be to have a separate function in each member of the array that calls the proper slideshow for that day. I'll update with a generic example.

Comment: Thanks again Patrick,

I will play around with what you have suggested and see if I can get it to work.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

The first thought should be **server-side**.

If that is not an option then you could do it with javascript/jquery with the limitations it brings. Javascript enabled browsers.

You could name your files accordingly ie. `image-19-7-2011.jpg` and use the `Date()` object to create the filename to use for the current date.

Something like

```
var d = new Date();
var filename = 'image-' + d.getDate() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getFullYear() + '.jpg';

document.getElementById('banner').src = '/path/to/' + filename;
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/rZaqx/

Comment: +1 this behavior should be implemented server side as even if you show/hide they will still be available on client side therefore "visible" for clients.

Comment: @rbhro, totally agree. i just provided the code for the case where server-side is not an option.. but the logic stands for both cases.

Comment: I agree completeley, however Server side access is nigh-on non existant with Netsuite which is the software that is in use for the site.

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date();
var date = now.getMonth() + "-" + now.getDay();
switch(date) {
  case "04-01":
    $('<p>APRIL FOOLS!</p>').appendTo("body");
    break;
  case "01-01":
    $('<p>Happy New Year!</p>').appendTo("body");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you want a different banner image for each day of the week.

If you aren't able to update the banner in the backend then it would be possible just to have all the banners on the page, hidden with the CSS `display: none`.

Then just use something like:

```
var date = new Date();
$("#banner" + date.getDay()).show();
```

This will work if you have 7 elements named banner0 for Sunday, banner1 for Monday, etc.

Alternatively, if you just want to change the banner image then you could set your CSS like so:

```
div#banner { background-image: url(default.jpg)} // Common styling
div#banner.day0 { background-image: url(image0.jpg); } // Image for Sunday
div#banner.day1 { background-image: url(image1.jpg); } // Image for Monday
div#banner.day2 { background-image: url(image2.jpg); } // Image for Tuesday
```

Then your jQuery could look like:

```
var date = new Date(); 
$("div#banner").addClass("day" + date.getDay());
```

Of course, the issue with both these options are that you need to have a different banner for each day. They're just some ways you can do it (but definitely not the only ways)